# Installing Ubuntu 18.4 on XPS 15 9570 - Tries to install on USB drive

Tags: dell, xps

I am trying to install Ubuntu and it goes into the installer, but the only disk it sees is the usb drive. I shrank my primary partition in windows, so I have space ready. I disabled secure boot in Bios. Do I need something more?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to go into the BIOS (<kbd>F2</kbd> key at startup), select **System Configuration**, then click on the <kbd>SATA Operation</kbd> box and choose the **AHCI** option.